# Combining \DTLgmeanforall with a conditional in a table created by datatool

Tags: conditionals, datatool

I am organizing a list of students an there marks for exams in a .csv Document. These are printed in a tabular environment with the help of datatool. The Table lists the marks an the resulting mean. As long as there is a mark in every row, all works fine. My problems begin when there is one mark missing.

I am looking for a way to check wether all marks are in a given row. If one mark is not in the row, data tool should ignore it while computing the mean.

For example: 
My example.csv looks similar to this:

```
name;vorname;note1;note2;note3
name1;vorname1;12;1;13
name2;vorname2;11;1;13
name3;vorname3;12;;1 --> missing mark 
name4;vorname4;4;1;13
name5;vorname5;;1;13 --> missing mark
name6;vorname6;12;;13 --> missing mark
```

I want the LaTeX Document to read the Data and compute the mean. This works fine for rows 1,2 and four. In the other rows I would like to have only the given marks added and then divided by the number of them. For example in row three: 12+1/2.

If I use \DTLmeanforall the row is divided by three. Is there a way to change this, if not all marks are present?

Thanks for your help.

Here is my latex document:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb{list}{example.csv}
\DTLsort{nachname}{list}
\begin{tabular}{clp{.1\textwidth}p{.1\textwidth}p{.1\textwidth}p{.2\textwidth}p{.1\textwidth}p{.2\textwidth}}

Nr. & \bfseries Nachname & \bfseries Vorname  & Mark1 & Mark2 & Mean first   Semester & Mark 3  & Mean Second Semester
\DTLforeach{list}{\nachname=nachname,\vorname=vorname,\mi=note1,\mii=note2,\miii=note3}{%
\DTLiffirstrow{\\ \hline}
{\\ \DTLifoddrow{\rowcolor{white}}{\rowcolor[gray]{.9}}}%
\theDTLrowi & \nachname & \vorname & \mi & \mii &
&\DTLmeanforall{\semi}{\mi,\mii} \DTLround{\semi}{\semi}{0} Punkte: \semi 
& \hando &  
\DTLmeanforall{\semii}{\semi,\miii} \DTLround{\semii}{\semii}{0}
}
\end{tabular}}
```